# Gets post_title with some custom post_id Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What i'm trying to do is getting the `post_title` of some customs 
like this

```
post 1 = "PHP"
post 2 = "ASP"
post 3 = "HTML"
post 4 = "CSS"
```

in array i want to chose post number 1,3,4 the answer must be in loop and get this results

```
PHP
HTML
CSS
```

Comment: Your question does'nt  understandable please add the more information that describe the post

Comment: i want to build a custom slide show with custom post id :(

Comment: Try get_posts functionn from wordpress

Comment: i'v try this 
$args = array('post__in' => array(18,76));
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $p) {
    echo $p["post_title"].'<br>';
}
but gives an error :
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Post as array

Comment: because it's object you should use '->' this operator i.e. $p->post_title

Comment: thank you all i problem solved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array('post__in' => array(1,3,4));
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $p) echo $p->post_title.'<br>';
```